# Simulating a full post request

Tags: c#, post, webclient

I am trying to simulate a post request using WebClient; However, When logging in using Firefox and debugging the request with firebug i find that after the POST request it automatically do some GET requests while using my code only do the POST request

MY CODE

```
//Handler is an overridden WebClient Class
        private async Task<byte[]> Post(string uri, string[] data)
        {
            var postData = new NameValueCollection();

            foreach (var info in data.Select(var => var.Split('=')))
            {
                postData.Add(info[0], info[1]);
            }

            return await Handler.UploadValuesTaskAsync(new Uri(uri), postData);
        }
```

Comment: Maybe the server is sending a 301/302 redirect response causing the client to perform a GET?

Comment: Nope all responses are 200 OK but the browser is performing those GETs ...

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't what you are asking for, AND its in VB, but hopefully it can help to point you in the right direction. It is what I use to make post requests on one of our websites. It works for simulating the POST data, hopefully you can incorporate some of that into what you are doing.

```
   Dim postData As String = String.Format("RedirectLocation=RequestMethod=&username={0}&password={1}", _username, _password)

   Dim _loginRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(loginurl)

           With _loginRequest
                .Method = "POST"
                .ContentLength = postData.Length
                .ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"                        
                .KeepAlive = True
                .AllowAutoRedirect = False

                .CookieContainer =  New CookieContainer

                Using writer As New StreamWriter(.GetRequestStream)
                    writer.Write(postData)
                End Using
                .Timeout = tsTimeOut.TotalMilliseconds
                _loginResponse = .GetResponse()
            End With
```

Comment: I am very thankful for your replay and well to help, however it seems that you are disabling auto redirect what is far from what i need to achieve

Comment: The part that I was trying to highlight, which I should have done a little better, was the `Using writer As New StreamWriter(.GetRequestStream)` where I write the post data to the Request Stream